# Is there a way to modify DPI or scanning resolution of an input device using python?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes, highdpi

I'm creating an application which tracks the distance traced by the mouse. I'd like to increase the DPI of the mouse to get the most precise measurements possible. I've modified the speed using SPI_SETMOUSESPEED but I don't think this actually modifies the DPI read by the mouse. How do Razer, Logitech, etc. manipulate the DPI through their apps? Can I do something similar to modify the mouse I'm using for this application?

Answer (score 1):

The DPI of your mouse is determined by the mouse manufacturer - - usually fixed at either 800 or 1200 (sometimes 1600).

You won't find it in Windows.

It's often only shown on the packaging (if it's shown at all) so if you don't have the packaging look for your mouse model on the manufacturer's website or a vendor's site.

Only expensive mice(such as Razer, Logitech, etc) have adjustable DPI value, on most others it's fixed.

**So for most mice, the only way is to change the speed of the mouse pointer.**

Refer: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4052284/accessories-how-do-i-change-mouse-sensitivity-dpi

Comment: @Evan Brittain Hi, does this help you?